# How to propagate data change from upper activity/fragment in stack to all other activity/fragment of that type in stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an Activity - Let's call it `A`

And back-stack is like it:

```
A1...A2...A3...An
```

( **...**'s are other activities between A's Activities)

if there is a change in data in `An` how to notify `A1...An-1` for this data change to update their views???

ps: **And of course without using setResult**

Answer (score 2):

Use EventBus to send event between activity.
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: tnx For your answer but in ps i said without using startActivityForResult and setResult

Answer (score 2):

I usually use  [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for returning simple data. And use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) (if I am lazy because it 's very simple) and can return complex data. Both broadcasting actions/events you want.